# How to trawl documents for keywords and create hyperlinks to relevant documents?

Tags: workflow

I have create a flow to create a new sharepoint page for each of our customers, it creates a folder structure in dropbox. Each device has its own document (i.e. DC01.docx), would it be possible to automatically trawl each document and where it finds keywords (hostnames normally), it hyperlinks that word to the relevant documents.
For example, where switch01.docx refers to DC01, a hyperlink is created on the work DC01 to DC01.docx

I expect i will need to create some sort of key file, but this is where my knowledge fails.

Comment: Is there no answer because i worded my question poorly or because there is no solution?